# How to compare two images and extract its difference?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have two sets of images which have the same size and pixels. Now I have to compare selectedFrame which is the 1st image to backImageFrame which is the 2nd image. I need to get the difference in the images and extract it so I can output it in a ImageBox. Now, I am using AbsDiff function of EmguCV

```
 selectedFrame.ROI = recArray[random];
 backImageFrame.ROI = recArray[random];
 // backImageFrame = selectedFrame.AbsDiff(backImageFrame);
 CvInvoke.AbsDiff(selectedFrame, backImageFrame, backImageFrame)
 imgTry.Image = backImageFrame;
 imageBox1.Image = selectedFrame;
```

The imgTry ImageBox doesn't have any value in it

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Image API to find the difference between one image and the other, then you can define a threshold for the difference to be considered and apply that.

The code will be something like:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame; //current Frame from camera
Image<Bgr, Byte> Previous_Frame; //Previiousframe aquired
Image<Bgr, Byte> Difference; //Difference between the two frames
int Threshold = 60; //stores threshold for thread access



Difference = Previous_Frame.AbsDiff(Frame); //find the absolute difference 
                 /*Play with the value 60 to set a threshold for movement*/    
Difference = Difference.ThresholdBinary(new Bgr(Threshold, Threshold, Threshold), new Bgr(255,255,255)); //if value > 60 set to 255, 0 otherwise
```

do followup with [this example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/CompareImages_-_Difference) to better understand.

Comment: Thanks! But in that example, the difference is not extracted from it's background. I need to extract their difference. 
http://s21.postimg.org/p3bv6kpw3/image.jpg
http://s21.postimg.org/jt6wfa5n7/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Image<Gray, Byte> img1 = picPrev.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
Image<Gray, Byte> img2 = picCurrent.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
Image<Gray, Byte> img3;
img3 = img1 - img2; //Here the difference is applied.
pictureBox3.Image = img3.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

**EmguCV AbsDiff based comparison**

```
Bitmap inputMap = //bitmap  source image
Image<Gray, Byte> sourceImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(inputMap);

Bitmap tempBitmap = //Bitmap template image
Image<Gray, Byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(tempBitmap);

Image<Gray, byte> resultImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(templateImage.Width, 
templateImage.Height);

CvInvoke.AbsDiff(sourceImage, templateImage, resultImage);

double diff = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(resultImage);

diff = (diff / (templateImage.Width * templateImage.Height)) * 100; // this will give you the difference in percentage
```

As per my experience, this is the best method compared to MatchTemplate based comparison. Match template failed to capture very minimal changes in two images.
But AbsDiff will be able to capture very small difference as well

Answer (score 0):

Using `AbsDiff`, I created a code that can compare two images using emgu cv.

Involves using three picture boxes and a menustrip.

```cs
private void subtractToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenFileDialog ofd2 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Mat Img1 = CvInvoke.Imread(ofd1.FileName);
            CvInvoke.Resize(Img1, Img1, 5);

            pictureBox1.Image = Img1.ToBitmap();

            Mat Img2 = CvInvoke.Imread(ofd2.FileName);
            pictureBox2.Image = Img2.ToBitmap();
            if (pictureBox1 != null && pictureBox2 != null)
            {
                Mat SubImg = new Mat();
                CvInvoke.AbsDiff(Img1, Img2, SubImg);

                pictureBox3.Image = SubImg.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```